# Vertical mega menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

How to create a vertical mega menu as shown in image using Bootstrap?

[image]

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="pill">Pill A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="pill">Pill B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="pill">Pill C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="pill">Pill D</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_a">
         <h4>Pane A</h4>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b">
         <h4>Pane B</h4>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_c">
         <h4>Pane C</h4>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d">
         <h4>Pane D</h4>
         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas.
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- tab content -->
</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt5sgqk9/)

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qt5sgqk9/

Comment: I couldn't get you right.. Are you trying to use CSS to also customize the look and feel of your vertical mega menu just like the example you've shown? If so, it requires you lots of custom CSS styles. And let me mention that it definitely doesn't require you Bootstrap!

You can simply use this jQuery plugin and CSS framework: https://myflashlabs.github.io/24component-bars/

Of course this plugin works with Bootstrap too. So you don't need to code it yourself all from the beginning when there's already a solution out there!